# Bootloader Jump the Application I2C problem

Tags: stm32, bootloader

I am trying to jump user application from boot code:

Boot code only include below lines:

```
int main()
{
        HAL_Init();
        SystemClock_Config();
        // Jump proccess start
        uint32_t reset_handler_add=*((volatile uint32_t*)(FLASH_APP_START_ADDRESS+4));
        void (*app_reset_handler)(void) = (void*)reset_handler_add;
        HAL_RCC_DeInit();                  
        HAL_DeInit();
        __HAL_RCC_SYSCFG_CLK_DISABLE(); 
        SysTick->CTRL = 0;                   
        SysTick->LOAD = 0;                   
        SysTick->VAL = 0;                    
        __disable_irq();     
        SCB->VTOR = FLASH_APP_START_ADDRESS;                                                        
        uint32_t msp_value = *((volatile uint32_t*)(FLASH_APP_START_ADDRESS));
        __set_MSP(msp_value);
        app_reset_handler();
while(1);
}
```

Also #define FLASH_APP_START_ADDRESS 0x080A0000 this is application code start address.

But when I jump the User application I2C not working .

In the User application I stuck in while (HAL_I2C_GetState(hi2c) != HAL_I2C_STATE_READY) function when I jump the User App. But If User App work on the base 0x080000000 address everything successfull, When I jump I have problem.

I changed flash.Ld file on User app:

```
MEMORY
{
RAM (xrw)      : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 192K
CCMRAM (rw)      : ORIGIN = 0x10000000, LENGTH = 64K
FLASH (rx)      : ORIGIN = 0x080A0000, LENGTH = 256K
}
```

And changed #define VECT_TAB_OFFSET 0xA0000 value.

Where is the faults ?

Comment: Your jump code seems correct.  Probably the problem is caused by init and deinit HAL in the bootloader.  Ideally the bootloader should not include HAL.

Comment: How can I solve this, why the problem caused by Init and deInit ?

Comment: I couldnt find any answer my question, anybody help ?

Answer (score 0):

There is an I2C init problem in stm32 microcontrollers. I dont know if your issue is related to the bootloader code but I had the same symptoms.

The easiest fix I found for this is to init the I2C clk before initializing the SDA and SCL pins:

```
void HAL_I2C_MspInit(I2C_HandleTypeDef* i2cHandle)
{

  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};
  if(i2cHandle->Instance==I2C1)
  {
  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_MspInit 0 */

  /* USER CODE END I2C1_MspInit 0 */
  
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_I2C1_CLK_ENABLE();       // <------ move this line here 

    /**I2C1 GPIO Configuration    
    PB6     ------> I2C1_SCL
    PB7     ------> I2C1_SDA 
    */
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_6|GPIO_PIN_7;
    ...
```

Comment: I solve the problem with this ; if I init DMA clocks in Bootloader code although there is no code about DMA in Bootloader  but DMA using in User APP than everything works. Why this occurs I dont know. Should dma clocks init in base (0x080000) address I dont know. Is there any idea for that ?